# Heroku gem shows up despite having heroku toolbelt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, heroku, heroku-postgres

in my project folder, when I run `heroku version`, I get `heroku-gem/3.32.0 (x86_64-linux) ruby/2.2.0` as one of the items, however in my home folder running the same command returns `heroku-toolbelt/3.42.50 (x86_64-linux) ruby/2.2.0`. How can I use heroku toolbelt in my project folder?

Comment: Uninstall gem like : `gem uninstall heroku`

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli, I tried to do that, but [this](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/15910951/) happened

Comment: yes please press `y` to uninstall and then upgrade your heroku toolbelt it will work!

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli, spot on, it worked, if you put it up as an answer I can accept it :)

Comment: Answer added, now you can accept that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution would be to uninstall the `heroku gem` like : `gem uninstall heroku`

and Upgrade `Heroku Toolbelt`.